# Nested Attributes in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

can anyone please walk me through Nested Attributes in Rails 3?

I have two Models: Certificates and Custodians, related as follows:

Certificate Model:

```
class Certificate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shareholder
  belongs_to :custodian
  belongs_to :issuer

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :custodian, :shareholder, :issuer 
end
```

Certificate Controller:

```
class CertificateController < ApplicationController
  def issue
    @certificate = Certificate.new
    @certificate.custodian.build
  end
end
```

My View:

```
<% form_for(:certificate, :url => {:action => 'testing'}) do |f| -%>

<div id="error">
    <%= f.error_messages %>
</div>

  <%= f.label :number, "Certificate Number" %>
  <%= f.text_field :number %>   <br/>

    <%= f.label :num_of_shares, "Number Of Shares" %>
    <%= f.text_field :num_of_shares %> <br/>

    <% f.fields_for :custodian do |custodian| -%>
        <%= custodian.label :name, "Custodian Name" %>
        <%= custodian.text_field :name %>
    <% end -%>

    <%= f.submit "Issue Certificate", :disable_with => 'Working....' %>

<% end -%>
```

Now, for some reason, in my controller on line 4: `@certificate.custodian.build`

I'm getting this error: `undefined method 'build' for nil:NilClass`

Can any one please help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**accepts_nested_attributes_for** should go on the side of one in the one-to-many relationship.

```
class Custodian < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :certificates
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :certificates
end
```

So, in your view, there should be no fields_for :custodian, it's on the wrong side. If you have to build a certificate from that view, you have to list custodians available, probably in a select box.

Comment: Thanks `Pejic` thats exactly what i'm trying to achieve. But rather than a select box, i plan on using Ajax to create an autocomplete field. But for now, i'm interested to get this done the way you described.

Comment: i can create a new instance variable with the Custodians listed and display a select box, but then how do i go back saving the association in the model?

Comment: Populate the select box with ID/Name option pairs. Here's a good guide as to how to do it, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease

This should get your basic form up and running. To do autocomplete, you need to build the JSON so that it passes something unique to the Custodians controller, like an ID or a name if the name is unique.

Answer (score 9):

With a belongs_to, it should be

```
@certificate.build_custodian
```

Comment: Thanks `guitsaru` that worked. But, my view is not rendering the `fields_for` part at all. Rest of the form is being rendered properly.

Answer (score 6):

This line

```
<% f.fields_for :custodian do |custodian| -%>
```

should be

```
<%= f.fields_for :custodian do |custodian| -%>
```