# Rails - Add many objects to another object type

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose that I've two controllers, "good" and "customer" and that I want add many goods to a single customer; in which way can I do this?

I mean, I need a customer's show view that list all goods associated to that project and a "add good to customer" used to add a new object to customer.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Sorry, I've explained me bad. My association is the following: 1 good <-> multiple customers and vice versa 1 customer <-> 1 good .As I wrote before customer's show view must list all goods associated and a "add good to customer" used to add a new object to custome. Is it change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to do that at the model level with an [association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and then allow for [nested attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867880/nested-attributes-in-rails-3).

It might look like this

**model**

```
class customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :goods
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :goods
end
```

Then in the views for customer you would want to have the nested form. This [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) gives a good overview for that. Because of the association and the `accepts` you can automatically inherit them in the controller. Also there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572665/how-do-i-create-the-view-for-the-has-one-association) that amplifies the explanation.

Comment: Sorry, I've explained me bad. My association is the following: 1 good <-> multiple customers and vice versa 1 customer <-> 1 good .As I wrote before customer's show view must list all goods associated  and a "add good to customer" used to add a new object to custome. Is it change anything?

Comment: @Marco So goods can have multiple customers and customers can have multiple goods?

Comment: No! goods can have multiple customers BUT customer can have ONLY one good. To understand better let's say that in details, good are pc hardware's model for me while customers are my client and let's say that I'm creating a web app to manage my stores.It's always a one to has_many relationship

Comment: @Marco There are some slight changes. I updated my answer to reflect that

Comment: OK thank you!Another question,I've seen that you've wrote "has_one :goods" but in class goods I've always the following right?class good < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :customers
end