# How to create Ruby on Rails custom form fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a Repair model which currently has may too many fields in the database - http://i.qyk.in/b0DwJ.png. This can be a pain for testing and I'm guessing it will be in the future as well.

I am looking to have a way to create custom form fields which will only be linked to this Repair model. I'm just curious as to how I would go about doing this?

These custom form fields would also need to accept content as well.

I'm guessing I would be using `has_many` and that?

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

That does sound like a `has_many`, probably with nested attributes (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867880/nested-attributes-in-rails-3) has some decent pointers on using nested attributes.
I hope this at least gets you started in a useful direction.