# How can I set the value to the nested column when signing up with Devise in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using rails3.

User model has one user_profile.
I just installed devise and its working fine.

I made  registrations_controller.rb and it has 'create', 'after_update_path_for(resource)
', and 'edit' actions.

If I want to make it input '45' to nested column of user_profile as default value, how can I code in registration controller???

Should I make another action called 'save/or new?' , and write this?

> @user.user_profile.language_id = '45'

Comment: I suggest you take a look at nested_attributes.  Here are a few links: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html, http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867880/nested-attributes-in-rails-3

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a default value for a particular field you can add this to your migration file like...

```
create_table :user_profile do |t|
  ...
  t.integer :language_id, :default => 45
end
```

...this will automatically set the lauguage_id value with the association is created.

Comment: as I said, I wanna do that in controller